# I am having issues updating my database from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I have shoppingbasket.php which has a HTML form, and is linked to incrementing.js
I have plus and minus buttons which update the quantity of the item in the basket, however I am having issues updating my database (in PHPMyAdmin) so that the 'basket' table updates automatically when someone uses the plus or minus buttons.

Shoppingbasket.php includes:

```
Print '<div id="list_item">
        <img src="Images/' . $img . '">
            <div id="rightside">
                <a href="singlepage.php?subject=' . $product_id . '">' . $name . '</a><br>
                <p>' . $subtitle . '</p><br>
                <form id="quantity" method="POST" action="">
                    <div class="numbers-row">
                        <input type = "text" id="' . $product_id . '" value="' . $quantity . '">

                    </div>
            
                </form>
            </div>
    </div>';
```

Incrementing.js includes:

```
$(function() {

    $(".numbers-row").append('<div class="inc button">+</div><div class="dec button">-</div>');

    $(".button").on("click", function() {
        var $button = $(this);
        var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

        if ($button.text() == "+") {
            var quantity = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
        } else {
            // Don't allow decrementing below zero
            if (oldValue > 0) {
                var quantity = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
            } else {
                quantity = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    var pid = $button.attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "basket2table.php",
        data: {  pid : pid, quantity: quantity, },
        success: function() {
            $button.parent().find("input").val(quantity);
        }
    });
});
```

Basket2table.php includes:

```
<?php include("dbconnect.php");

if(isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];  
}
if(isset($_POST['pid'])){
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
}

$sql_query = "UPDATE Basket 
                SET quantity='$quantity' 
              WHERE product_ID='$pid' ";
$result = $db-> query($sql_query);
?>
```

Comment: _Small but relevant point_ **phpMyAdmin** is a tool written in PHP to make maintaining a **MYSQL** database easier for beginners. It is not a database

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: You are leaving your db wide open to SQL injection by not using `prepared statements`

Comment: Also worth nothing perhaps with the design of the database: If you update the basket using `product_id` alone - whose order are you updating?

Comment: This question has many issue with writing proper code. BTW you can use $(document).on('click','<dynamically added elements>',function(){})

Comment: I'm not too familiar with jQuery so may be incorrect here but you are adding the buttons dynamically  as a string of HTML. Do the `button click` functions fire the ajax request OK?

Comment: The AJAX call isn't inside the `click` handler.

Comment: There's no `id` attribute in the button.

Comment: there's no `.button` element in the html code. try adding it to your input as a class

Comment: @AdisonMasih - the `.button` elements are added dynamically but as I hinted to and was pointed out by @Barmar - they are not doing anything in terms of the ajax request

Comment: @Barmer thank you! I have moved it to inside click function and changed the id attribute to button.parent.attr(id) and it is working perfectly!